# Did require become replaced by require_relative for files?

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby 2.1.5 and whenever I download code that uses `require` to include a file, I get errors. Changing `require` to `require_relative` fixes the problem. For example, if I use the example code from [rspec](http://rspec.info/), I get the following error output.

```
mario@crunchbang:~/projects/rspec_test$ rspec bowling_spec.rb 
/home/mario/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bowling (LoadError)
    from /home/mario/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/mario/projects/rspec_test/bowling_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
    from /home/mario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/mario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
    from /home/mario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/mario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
    from /home/mario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
    from /home/mario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /home/mario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
    from /home/mario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/mario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/mario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/mario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Is there something wrong with my Ruby set up or can `require` no longer be used the way it was in earlier versions of Ruby?

Comment: Can you post the spec file. (bowling_spec.rb)

Comment: The rspec.info site is old and quite out of date. We're working on a new version of the site (which'll launch soon). You can view it at http://rspec.github.io/. As the example videos show, `bowling.rb` is intended to go in `lib` (where implementation code normally goes outside Rails apps). RSpec puts `lib` on the load path so that you can require files relative to it. If you move `bowling.rb` into `lib`, `require 'bowling'` from the spec file should work.

Comment: Posting bowling_spec.rb so that this post has meaning if the rspec site changes its code.

```bowling_spec.rb
require 'bowling'

describe Bowling, "#score" do
  it "returns 0 for all gutter game" do
    bowling = Bowling.new
    20.times { bowling.hit(0) }
    bowling.score.should eq(0)
  end
end```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` works exactly the same as it did before: it searches the `$LOAD_PATH`. What *has* changed is the default `$LOAD_PATH`: the current directory `.` was removed from it, for various maintenance and security reasons.

In almost all cases, you don't want to load a file relative to the current working directory anyway (after all, the CWD is controlled by the user, so you don't even know what it is, how could you then reliably load a file from there?), you want to load it relative to the current file … which is exactly what `require_relative` does.

By the way: this change was relased 7 years ago, made before that, and announced even before *that*, I don't know where you are getting that code from, but I would be highly suspicious of code that hasn't been maintained for such an extended period of time (almost 10 years).

Comment: Definite +1 for the warning about being suspicious of old code.

Comment: Please look at the [Rspec official video](http://rspec.github.io/) for this. That's will help you to understand, what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Require only searches for files in Ruby's load path. Prior to 1.9, the current folder (.) was included in the load path. See [Kernel#require](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-require)

if you've been writing code with paths relative to the current directory it's normal that `require` doesn't work. You can either add `.` to the load path:

```
rspec -I . my_script.rb
```

Or as you have found, `require_relative` resolves the argument relative to the path to the file it is contained in. People also used to use `__FILE__` to achieve this before `require_relative` was available.

You can also add the -I option to your .rspec file or setup your load paths in your spec_helper.rb

Comment: `.` was removed for a reason, it's a security and maintenance nightmare. Please, just use `require_relative`, that's what it's there for.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `require` you need to pass the absolute path for the file.

`require_relative` is working as it depends on the relative path.

Edit the code part where you `require` the file to absolute file path and it should work well.